# translating value of a column of a spread sheet with google app script

Tags: date, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet that has a column with date formatted data ([see here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uGAxxE-dlyPuStEsww9aiKIrFwvZrg2HX1CpwKikBso/edit?usp=sharing)).
However, when i get the values with (sheet previously defined):

```
var array = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
```

and i try to get dates from the dates column,

```
var date = array[somerow][Column_dates];
```

i got a number like: `42905.15239780092` (for first row with date, that is supposed to be a today date).

But if i use `(new Date()).getTime()` i got something like: `1497907218972`.

Both are completely different....?

What i would like to do is compare both dates....

What's wrong?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Someone else will probably be able to provide a better explanation but I think:

The number `42905.15239780092` is a date time format.

The number `1497907218972` is a time format.

[JavaScript Date Objects](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Comment: i see, is there a way to get the date (dd/mm/aaaa) from the first number?

Comment: or at least convert one number format to the other?

Answer (score 0):

i found a workaroud, that is using `getDisplayValues()` instead of `getValues()` to get the array. This give me a date string on the column with dates that it is easier to work with...